# COMException HRESULT: 0x800A9D9F with Application.run method call to MS Access from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2016

Message reads: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A9D9F

Environment: Access 2016, Windows 10, IIS 10.0; ASP.NET 4.7, URL http://127.0.0.1/openAccess3.aspx. The code is in an ASP.NET file on an ISS web server. No internet involvement. Browser and ISS are both on my desktop. Here is the code in question:

```
Dim oAccessApp
oAccessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
oAccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WPE_Dev\WPE_Support.accdb")
oAccessApp.Run("ReadJSON")
oAccessApp.Quit
```

If I comment out oAccessApp.Run("ReadJSON"). Access opens and closes just as you would expect.

In the Access Trust Center I set Macro Settings to “Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)" That didn't help.

Comment: So createobject does work? This means that you need to be running the x64 bit version of Access - or you have to run IIS in x32 bit mode. Since Access does seem to open, then the routine ReadJSON will have to be marked as a public sub (not a function), and in a standard code module, not a forms code module.

Comment: Thank you Albert. I am running 64 bit Office 2016 and 64 Bit Windows 10. I did change the function to a sub. I still get the same error. Owen

Comment: As noted, then on the  server browse to the database. Double click to launch, then hit ctrl-g to jump to debug window. Now type in your sub name to run "readJason". The routine should run. If it does not, the your above code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS I set the Process Model Identity to an admin account. The code now runs. It is possible that another tweak i made also helped, but this change is what got it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue (not from ASP but from a NET executable) by allowing Trusted Locations on my network.

On Access:
`File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Trusted Locations`
Activate `Allow Trusted Locations on my network` or perhaps add a new location (didn't tried)

[Add, remove, or change a trusted location](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, it's not officially supported (highlighting by me):

> **Microsoft** does not currently recommend, and **does not support**, **Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application** or component (**including** ASP, **ASP.NET**, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Source: [MS KB 257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Thus, the "correct" solution would be to migrate your `ReadJSON` code to classic ASP (VBScript) or, better, ASP.NET (C# or VB.NET) and run it outside an MS Access container.

*(I am aware that this is a potentially costly solution and that workarounds, even if officially unsupported, might be worth the risk. You just need to be aware that what you are doing is officially unsupported and might stop working at any time.)*